# Binary search that returns the index where the value should be inserted

Tags: java, binary-search

I need to do a binary search that in addition to the normal function, when the value is not found it returns the index where I must insert a new element for sorting. In the code below, the second for works to do a search of the index where the element to be exchanged. I need to do a function that replaces this with a binary search. What would this method look like?

```
void insertion (int n, int v[])
{
   for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
   int x = v[j];
   int i;
// this for searches where the value should be inserted
   for (i = j-1; i >= 0 && v[i] > x; --i) 
        v[i+1] = v[i];
        v[i+1] = x;
   }
}
```

I know that normal binary search is like this. What do I need to change?

```
    static int BinarySearchR (int [] array, int l, int r, int key) {
        int mid = ((r - l) / 2) + l;
        if (array[mid] == key) return mid;
        else if (array[mid] > key) return BinarySearchR(array, l, mid- 1, key);
        else if(array[mid] < key) return BinarySearchR(array, mid + 1, r, key); 
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: how would be the method

Comment: Do you have to use a recursive binary search?

Comment: recursive or iterative

Answer (score 1):

With some adjustments it worked:

```
public static int BuscaBinariaI(int [] arr, int l, int r, int n) {
        int mid = 0;
            while(l < r){
                mid = l + (r - l)/2;
                if(arr[mid] == n) {
                    return -1;
                } 
                else if(arr[mid] > n){
                    r = mid - 1;
                    BuscaBinariaI( arr, l, r, n);
                }
                else {
                    l = mid + 1;
                    BuscaBinariaI( arr, l, r, n);
                }
            }
            if (mid>=arr.length) return arr.length;
            else if(arr[mid] > n) return mid ;
            else return mid + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int)) provides this:

```
int foundPos = Arrays.binarySearch(array, key);
if (foundPos < 0) {
    // Not found:
    int insertPos = ~foundPos;
}
```

A positive result gives the found position/index.
A negative result gives the one's complement of the insert position.

An other advantage are the many overloads of this function for other types,
and other variants for subarrays.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I can't use Arrays.binarySearch. But it is very good to know.

Comment: Yes I tought this might be homework, but the trick of  `~foundPos` (or `-(foundPos+1)`) to return both position and found/not found one should have seen. The alternative of returning just a position has a huge disadvantage of needing an element comparision, guarded by an index check as the position could be after the array's end.

Comment: Why are you using a tilde rather than a negative sign?

Comment: @NomadMaker Tilde is the one's complement operator, ~0 = -1 and ~(-1) = 0. ~foundPos == -(foundPos+1). The algorithm uses the ones complement, that turns all non-negative numbers in negative numbers. But the javadoc targeted also oridinary programmers unaccustomed to the rare bit mask tilde operator. I prefer using it, as it is shorter and much less error prone: ~i versus -(i+1).